# how to reflect with ssreflect: unable to unify ?x == ?y with "n = n0"

Tags: coq, ssreflect

EDIT: I found it! I had forgotten about a coercion. Please ignore this :)

I am learning ssreflect and am stuck on how to proceed here. My proof state is the following:

```
 n, n0 : nat
  ============================
  n = n0 -> n == n0
```

At first, I tried move/eqP, because I thought that would "apply" eqP to n=n0, where "apply" means "get n==n0 out of the reflection given by eqP".
However, this attempt produced:

```
Illegal application (Non-functional construction): 
The expression "eqP ?i" of type "?x = ?y"
cannot be applied to the term
 "?y0" : "?T0"
```

I'm confused on what y0 and T0 are supposed to be.
I also tried

`intros H. eapply (introT eqP) in H.`

which produced the error

```
Unable to apply lemma of type "?x = ?y -> ?x == ?y"
on hypothesis of type "n = n0".
```

I tried to pass in explicit arguments n0 and n to eqP, just to see if it would work, with

`pose proof (eqP n n0).`
but this gave an error of

```
In environment
n, n0 : nat
H : n = n0
The term "n" has type "nat"
while it is expected to have type
 "is_true (?x == ?y)".
```

So, it seems like eqP both wants and doesn't want explicit instantiations for ?x and ?y. I would really appreciate some conceptual explanation as to why move/eqP isn't behaving how I think it should, and what is actually going on with the types of eqP and (introT eqP).

If it is relevant, I am importing

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssrnat ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype.
```

from ssreflect.

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error: `move/eqP` works for me. I tried Coq 8.9, 8.10 and 8.11. Can you post the full example (with imports and the goal statement)?

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured out the problem; I had a coercion that I forgot about, so the actual goal was
  Nat n0 = Nat n1 -> n0 == n1

Comment: Ah, that was an instance of the canonical `Set Printing All.` problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake! I had a coercion that I forgot about; my actual proof state was Nat n = Nat n0 -> n ==n0.